# Neural network accuracy optimization

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I have constructed an ANN in keras which has 1 input layer(3 inputs), one output layer (1 output) and two hidden layers with with 12 and 3 nodes respectively.

[image]

The way i construct and train my network is:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("sorted output.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:3]
Y = dataset[:,3]
# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)
```

Sorted output csv file looks like:

[image]

so after 150 epochs i get: **loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6970 - val_acc: 0.1429**

My question is: how could i modify my NN in order to achieve higher accuracy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neil Slater already provided a long list of helpful general advices.

In your specific examaple, normalization is the important thing. If you add the following lines to your code

```
...
X = dataset[:,0:3]
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

you will get 100% accuracy on your toy data, even with much simpler network structures. Without normalization, the optimizer won't work.

Comment: @Adriano10: Answer is missing an `n`,  try `from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`

Comment: Just one remark: this is usually called [standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) (subtracting the mean and dividing the by the standard deviation in order to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of 1). [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) is much more loosely defined and can have several meanings (e.g. transforming to the [0,1] range or so).

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following things. I have written this roughly in the order of importance - i.e. the order I would try things to fix the accuracy problem you are seeing:

1. Normalise your input data. Usually you would take mean and standard deviation of training data, and use them to offset+scale all further inputs. There is a [standard normalising function in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) for this. Remember to treat your test data in the same way (using the mean and std from the training data, not recalculating it)
2. Train for more epochs. For problems with small numbers of features and limited training set sizes, you often have to run for thousands of epochs before the network will converge. You should plot the training and validation loss values to see whether the network is still learning, or has converged as best as it can.
3. For your simple data, I would avoid relu activations. You may have heard they are somehow "best", but like most NN options, they have types of problems where they work well, and others where they are not best choice. I think you would be better off with tanh or sigmoid activations in hidden layers for your problem. Save relu for very deep networks and/or convolutional problems on images/audio.
4. Use more training data. Not clear how much you are feeding it, but NNs work best with large amounts of training data.
5. Provided you already have lots of training data - increase size of hidden layers. More complex relationships require more hidden neurons (and sometimes more layers) for the NN to be able to express the "shape" of the decision surface. [Here is a handy browser-based network allowing you to play with that idea and get a feel for it](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/classify2d.html).
6. Add one or more [dropout layers](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout) after the hidden layers or add some other regularisation. The network could be over-fitting (although with a training accuracy of 0.5 I suspect it isn't). Unlike relu, using dropout is pretty close to a panacea for tougher NN problems - it improves generalisation in many cases. A small amount of dropout (~0.2) might help with your problem, but like most hyper-parameters, you will need to search for the best values.

Finally, it is always possible that the relationship you want to find that allows you to predict Y from X is not really there. In which case it would be a correct result from the NN to be no better than guessing at Y.

Comment: I tried to increase the training data but i noticed that when i increased it the accuracy droped. Why could this happen?

Comment: @Adriano10: Not really possible to say without getting heavily involved in the problem. However, it could be random fluctuations (accuracy < 50% is likely to be breakage elsewhere first). I wrote my answer in the order I would try things. So you should look at normalisation first - those high positive numbers in your input are going to stop any NN from working properly.

Comment: Thanks a million! That answer is great! If you do not mind, I have a question related. I believe this is a reason for another question, though. About the second option, could you clarify how we can see network converges or still learns?

Comment: @MustafaMuratARAT: Plot (or watch the values of) the loss function or whichever metric you want to optimise. If the network is learning, the value will improve. If it converges and is stable the learning will slow down asymptotically (this may be noisy for a stochastic learning approach). If you are looking for a network that generalises, using a cross-validation set - which is a common scenario - then it also is possible to overfit and have the cross-validation loss values get worse, and you need to look for that. Technically in that last case, you would stop learning before convergence . . .